# How do I retrieve a list of groups for each user using Alfresco Javascript API

Tags: javascript-framework, alfresco

I'm totally new to Alfresco and their Javascript API so please bear that in mind...

I want to be able to view a list of groups for every user in Alfresco repository.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
  var gens = search.luceneSearch("TYPE:\"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}person\"");
  var logFile = space.childByNamePath("log_user_groups.csv");
  if (logFile == null) {
      logFile = space.createFile("log_user_groups.csv");
   }
   logFile.content = "";



   for (var i=0; i<gens.length;i++) {
     logFile.content += gens[i].properties["cm:userName"]+"\n";

     var groupes= people.getContainerGroups(gens[i]);

     for (var j=0; j<groupes.length;j++) {
       logFile.content += "\t"+groupes[j].properties.shortName +"\t";
       logFile.content += "\t"+groupes[j].properties.fullName +"\t";
       logFile.content += "\t"+groupes[j].properties.displayName +"\n";
     }
  }
```

The file is created with the user name shown correctly.  However the group properties 'shortName', 'fullName' and 'displayName' are all null.  In fact I printed out all the properties of the 'groupes' object and every field of the object is 'undefined'.

Does any body know what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Norm.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.  The version of Alfresco is 3.2

Comment: Do you only want top level groups, or all groups? i.e. if user Fred is a member of Group A, which is itself a member of group B, do you want both groups A and B for Fred, or just one of them?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr.  Thanks for your query.  I'd like both groups A and B for Fred.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the wrong properties name.

You need the following:

- Full Name: `groupes[j].properties["usr:authorityName"]`
- Display Name: `groupes[j].properties["usr:authorityDisplayName"]`
- Short Name: I don't know :) maybe `groupes[j].properties["usr:authorityShortName"]`

You can also just get the NodeRef id.

Then login to Alfresco explorer. Then go to the administration console --> Node Browser

Paste the id (it should be something like `workspace://spacesStore//biglongUUID`).There you can see al the properties related to the group.

Or you could just loop the `groupes[k].properties` map and print all the properties.

Comment: Hi Tahir.  I don't want the username of the person but the actual *group name(s)* the person belongs to.

Comment: Hi Norm, Authority stands for User or Group. So AuthorityName should be group name. Have you tried it? Because the cm namespace is only used for authority after 3.2. So till 3.2 (maybe 3.3) it has always been the usr namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to turn it on its head. Instead, for each group ask what groups and what users it contains. At the end, invert it.

You'll want to start with the Root Groups. The `groups` JS object in Alfresco will give you these, and others. It's implemented by `ScriptAuthorityService`, so you'll likely want to look at the [JavaDocs](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/security/authority/script/ScriptAuthorityService.html)

First up, get the root groups

```
var rootGroups = groups.getAllRootGroups() ;
```

For each group, get all the users in the group (direct and inherited) with `getAllUsers()`, and store those somewhere. Now, get all the child groups with `getChildGroups()`. Process each of these in the same way, recursing as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar (a complete list of groups) so I did this:

```
var temp = [];

function addGroups (groups)
  {
    for each (group in groups)
      {
        temp.push(group.getDisplayName());
        addGroups(group.getChildGroups());
      }
  }

addGroups(groups.getAllRootGroups());
```

This works to a point.  The problem is that getDisplayName() returns a very non-pretty group name.  Normally when dealing with documents and displaying a group name associated with a user I would do people.getContainerGroups() and use group.properties["cm:authorityName"] to get a displayable name (as mentioned above), however the groups I receive from getAllRootGroups() do not have properties (group.properties is undefined).

Does anyone have any idea why the group list returned this way wouldn't have the same properties as those returned by people.getContainerGroups()?

Comment: OK, I was full of crap here.  It turns out there is no "readable" group name at all.  I misunderstood what I was doing previously (I wrote it many months ago) and thought that I was getting a readable group name, instead at a later time I am converting the group name into a readable name using the localization string bundles.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "readable" group name. I am working with workflow API and one of the props has the value `{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}authorityContainer Node Ref: workspace://SpacesStore/something something`
Now this value is of type Authority Container right? So I should be able to to .properties["cm:authorityName"], but it says undefined even for the properties field. i.e. when I do .properties and try to fetch the map, it says undefined. What is happening here? Why am I not able to fetch props? And what do you mean by readable group name? Thanks

Comment: the value that I printed in the comment above is from ftl file. It seems like an instance of authorityContainer, but when I try to send myprop.properties to ftl, and try to print it, it gives me undefined. It is instead supposed to say that can not convert map to string or something of that sort. 
Thanks.